# How to select the next records in database?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables tableA and tableB, I have to insert data from tableA to tableB. Firstly, I will select the data from tableA and then insert into tableB.

```
$sq = $db->prepare("SELECT userid, balance from plus_wallet order by id desc 
    limit 0,100");
```

and so on till `$sq->close();`

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `plus_user_wallet`
    (`userid`, `balance`, `update_time`) 
    VALUES(?,?,NOW() + INTERVAL 45000 second)");
```

and so on till `$sq->close();`

Now my question is: as I have number of records say, 100 and i want to select 100 records at a time,and then insert them, again next 100 records should be selected and code should execute. I want to know how can I do this.?? How can I select the next 100 records after the code executed for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` syntax and secondly use `OFFSET` in `LIMIT` clause

```
INSERT INTO `plus_user_wallet` (`userid`, `balance`, `update_time`) 
SELECT userid, balance, NOW() + INTERVAL 45000 SECOND
  FROM plus_wallet 
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 100
```

Then to insert next 100 rows you change OFFSET in LIMIT

```
LIMIT 100, 100
      ^^^
```

Comment: @VishalParkash Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?